# Omitting the refference to a particular logarithmic base - order notation

Tags: notation, logarithms, computational-complexity

How can I prove by using the Order notation definition that we can conventionally refer to an algorithm taking "log time", without referring to a particular logarithmic base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\log_an=(\lg_ab)(\log_bn)$, you have that $\log_an$ is just a constant multiple of $\log_bn$, and we know that constant multiples are invisible to asymptotic estimates.